# ASP.NET MVC5 some png images causing server error when viewed in Chrome emulation mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, google-chrome, mobile, internal-server-error

I think there's a good chance that I may be going insane! :)

I've got an MVC5 project that's been working great, there's nothing hugely complex about it, it's got a layout for mobile and a layout for desktop, there's some references to javascript files and images files all of which are working perfectly on the both versions using Chrome, IE, Firefox, Safari etc.... However, and here's where it gets weird is that on desktop a png loads fine, if I'm emulating a mobile, png returns a server error...

The server error is as so:

> 'c:/users/###########/documents/visual studio
>   2013/Projects/###############/################/Content/images/modal_background.png'
>   is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException:
>   'c:/users/#########/documents/visual studio
>   2013/Projects/########/############/Content/images/modal_background.png'
>   is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): 'c:/users/##########/documents/visual
>   studio
>   2013/Projects/###############/#################/Content/images/modal_background.png' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.]
>   System.Web.Util.UrlPath.CheckValidVirtualPath(String path) +9877969
>   System.Web.Util.UrlPath.Combine(String appPath, String basepath,
>   String relative) +131    System.Web.VirtualPath.Combine(VirtualPath
>   relativePath) +160    System.Web.HttpContext.RewritePath(String path,
>   Boolean rebaseClientPath) +131
>   System.Web.HttpContext.RewritePath(String path) +6
>   FiftyOne.Foundation.Mobile.Detection.Feature.ImageOptimiser.OptimisedImageResponse(HttpContext
>   context) +2731
>   FiftyOne.Foundation.Mobile.Detection.DetectorModule.OnPostAuthorizeRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +978
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +136    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34249

I don't understand what could be happening and I'm sure this wasn't an issue until a few days ago. I've been looking at everything that might be different between the two layouts and the style sheets they're including, but nothing is different.

Here's what's really weird....

I load up the image in Chrome directly with the emulator turned off
http://localhost:9118/Content/images/modal_background.png

It loads up no problem.

I turn the emulator on, say Apple iPhone 6 and hit refresh and hey presto, I get the server error message!

Turn the emulator off, hit refresh and it works. I'm guessing the problem must lie with Chrome. It all works fine in IE, loads the pngs without issue.. All works in Firefox as well.

What's even stranger is that some pngs are loading up fine in emulation mode (in the same folder) and others are not... I thought at first it was an underscore in the name, but even after renaming the files, they return server errors. But the same files work fine in desktop view, it's only mobile emulator again... Why some pngs are working I simply don't know.

I've restarted and got the latest version of Chrome so really just wondering if anyone else has experienced this, or perhaps I'm just going mad... :)

Thanks!